# Understanding Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context

Tags: php, fatal-error

I would like to understand exactly what this error means in PHP: how the error can be created on purpose and how to avoid or fix it.
In my simple example below, I got this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context in line 11

Line 11 is the following line:

```php
response['error'] = "Error: B is less that C <br />";
```

Here is the erroneous code:

```php
$response = [];
$a = 4;
$b = 8;
$c = 9;
$d = 29;

if($a !== $b){
    $response['error'] = "Error: A is not equal to B <br />";
}elseif($b < $c){
    response['error'] = "Error: B is less that C <br />";
}
if($d > $c){
    response['success'] = "Success: D is greater than C<br />";
}

echo $response['error'];
echo $response['success'];
```

**My expectation is:**

Making sure this exception is correctly handled

I know the variables are defined, otherwise the error would be:

> Notice: Undefined variable

Comment: it's due to a syntax error. 

use command php -l <filename> it will give you the exact error.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You have forgotten to include the `$` before the word `response`.

This is apparent in lines 11 and 14 like so:

```php
response['error'] = "Error: B is less that C <br />";
```

You should change it to:

```php
$response['error'] = "Error: B is less that C <br />";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Always remember '$' is very important in PHP to declare variables. I am glad my answer helped.

Comment: I'm missing no `$` and yet still get this error. Quite a misleadingly accepted answer for a question titled "Understanding" the error.

Comment: @Kröw - Can you share the code you are running ?

Comment: It would be great if the error said: Any chance you forgot your $?